# Shorten url in expressionengine

Tags: .htaccess, expressionengine

I use the cms expressionegine. I want to shorten my url

from
http://sionvalais.com/live/sionvalais
to
http://sionvalais.com/sionvalais

'sionvalais' is the weblog name in EE
live is the subdirectory in which EE is installed. Would someone be so kind as to help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# rewrites http://sionvalais.com/sionvalais/* to expression engine
# respectively http://sionvalais.com/live/sionvalais/index.php*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !\/live*
RewriteRule ^sionvalais/?(.*)$ live/sionvalais/index.php?$1 [L]

# rewrites http://sionvalais.com/live/sionvalais* to http://sionvalais.com/sionvalais*
# and sets http status code 301, so search engines 'forget' about your live directory
RewriteCond $1 !\/index\.php*
RewriteRule ^live/sionvalais(.*)$ /sionvalais$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Now it makes the main page url even longer: sionvalais.com/live/index.php/sionvalais , while I need sionvalais.com/sionvalais . For an article page I need sionvalais.com/sionvalais/snowcam_portal_of_europe but I get /live/live/sionvalais/index.ph

Comment: Sorry to hear that, works damn fine in my sandboy. Maybe you need a RewriteBase? I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to try in your .htaccess file:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond $1 !^live
  RewriteRule ^sionvalais(.*)$ live/sionvalais$1
```

It may need more refinement, but it seems to work in a very basic sandbox.